# How to display the ajax response frequently in pop up window

Tags: php, ajax

```
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url:"<?php echo TESTMINE_APP_URL; ?>/ajax/export-details",
            data:'paginationHash='+paginationHash+'&exportType='+exportType+'&userId='+userId,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(requestId) 
            {
                setInterval(function () {
                var status = checkStatusOfRequest(requestId);
                //here status has to show in pop up window
                }, 9000);

            }
       });
```

Comment: Are you wanting to call the ajax every 9 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I am calling ajax every 9 second and its response  message should be display in pop up window.

Comment: No, you are calling ajax once and calling checkStatusOfRequest every 9 seconds on the same 1 request. Explained in answer.

Comment: yes.. Every 9 second i am calling checkStatusOfRequest function.In that function using ajax its fetcheds status of data and return back to control

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write the result to a popup window, you could use:

```
success: function(requestId){
  var popup = window.open("");
  popup.document.write('<html><body>Status: <span id="status"></span></body></html>');

  setInterval(function(){
     var status = checkStatusOfRequest(requestId);
     popup.document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = status;
  }, 9000)
}
```

Comment: First ajax call for insert the details after that I will get requestId using that request Id every frequent interval I am calling checkStatusOfRequest() function to check the status and that should be display in pop up

Comment: Thanks..In that opend window ,it has to update the status.If status is 'ready',then it enable the button in that window.

Comment: success: function(requestId){
     var popup = window.open("sample1.php",500,500);
     popup.document.write('<html><body>Status: <span id="status"></span></body></html>');
    
     setInterval(function(){
     var status = checkStatusOfRequest(requestId);
     popup.document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = status;
     }, 9000)
   }